# Husserl's Logical Investigations volume II as entry point for Phenomenology

Tags: phenomenology, husserl

I have read that Edith Stein (in one of her biographies), got introduced to Phenomenology by being told to read Husserl's Logical Investigations volume II, and she had a background in Psychology (she had taken 2 semesters), so my question is, would it be a good idea to get started in Phenomenology by reading Husserl's Logical Investigations volume II? And why not volume I?

Comment: Why not try both as an experiment - and see which is the better approach for you?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks!

Comment: *Ideas* was really helpful for me!!